# iOS5 Simulator on XCode5-GM

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

On new XCode5-GM Apple stopped to support older simulators (they are not included in the XCode5 bundle). I would need at least a 5.0 simulator in order to test my apps because I would like to still support iOS5: I have no reasons for not doing it and iPad1 runs on it.

Is there any way to install and run iOS5 Simulator on XCode5 ?

Comment: How about going to  Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and downloading the iOS 5.1 simulator ?

Comment: I don't have 5.x under Preferences->Downloads, only 6.x

Comment: Maybe you should change your question to "Why is the iOS 5.x simulator not available to me in Xcode 5?" (FWIW, it's not available for me either.)

Comment: I will change the question when I will be sure that the io5 simulator is available for someone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://devforums.apple.com/message/859595#859595

<< OS Simulator 5.0/5.1 is available only on Mountain Lion.

If you're running on Mavericks, you'll only see iOS 6.0/6.1/7.0 >>

Comment: Anyone found an official statement from Apple?

Comment: @NathanHazout my answer is from Sept 26... the post is from Oct. I've tested the same vers. of Xcode in ML and Mavericks - I can confirm the above "behavior"...

Answer (score -4):

The iOS 5 simulator is still available, it's just not in the initial download (presumably for size reasons). You can install it as follows:

In XCode 5, open the following menu:

`XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads`

...and you'll be able to download iOS 5, 5.1, 6, and 6.1 simulators.

Comment: I don't have 5.x under Preferences->Downloads, only 6.x

Comment: Yes. Which version of XCode 5 are you using - the GM? I am running 5A1412, and I can see iOS 5 and 6 simulators available for download.

Comment: I have the GM too (5A1412) and it only lists 6.0 and 6.1 as downloadable.

Comment: Weird. I'm not on Mavericks, so unless that's it I have no idea why I can see them but you can't. Do you have XCode 4 installed as well, or just 5?

Comment: I have just 5 installed.

Comment: It appears to be related to Mavericks.  This is the best answer I've seen so far on the issue, unfortunately. https://devforums.apple.com/message/911139#911139