# XCode 5.0.1 and iOS 5.1 simulator issue

Tags: xcode, simulator

After upgrading XCode to 5.0.1 on Mavericks I can't install iOS 5 simulator, it's removed from Download section... Is it only happening to me or does anyone else has similar issue?

[image]

Is it possible to install 5.1 simulator from outside of Xcode Downloads page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I face the same thing when I installed the XCode4.5. Then I copied the SDK from my old xcode to the new xcode.
The SDK is located in the following path.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk 

 /Applications/Xcode4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's working correctly, I just hope that simulator from older xcode will work as expected...

Comment: I have copied the SDK to XCode5.0.1. But still can't run iOS 5 simulator.

Comment: I have all the simulator SDK in that folder but still I can't run any application under iOS5. In Xcode 5 I can select iOS 5 as target, but the emulator always starts in 7. Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: I can confirm this answer also solves the problem where, on Mountain Lion, I upgraded from **Xcode 5.0 to 5.1** and Apple rudely deleted my **Simulator sdk for iOS 5.1**. Fortunately I had a backup, as I use Parallels 9 virtual machines for all my development work. From the old virtual machine I extracted the `iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk` and moved a copy to my other VM. I don't know if it’s necessary, but I used BatChmod.app to change the "group" permissions from "wheel" to "admin" to match the other "sdk" folders, while checking the "Apply to enclosed folders" box.

Comment: @BasilBourque You don't need to change permissions.

Answer (score 42):

Unfortunately, iOS Simulator 5.0 and 5.1 don't work on Mavericks. The reason for this is best explained by gparker on the developer forums (https://devforums.apple.com/message/911139#911139):

> The iOS simulator does not duplicate some of the low-level parts of iOS. For example, it uses the host OS X's kernel instead of trying to virtualize the iOS kernel. The iOS simulator requires that these subsystems look sufficiently similar between the simulated iOS and the host OS X. When a new host OS X changes too much it can break old simulators. At that point somebody makes an engineering and cost decision to either update the old simulator or drop support for it.

Not the answer you and I were hoping to find. You could of course run Mountain Lion in Parallels for testing iOS 5.x.

Comment: Makes sense, but it's a pity that they didn't mentioned that. Also I don't believe it will force users to buy new iPads, instead it will make developers lives harder...

Comment: I've got Mountain Lion running as a virtual partition in Parallels Desktop. Even though the downloads for the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulators are there, I can't select it to run an app on them.

Answer (score 4):

iOS Simulator 5.0/5.1 is available only on Mountain Lion.  If you're running on Mavericks, you'll only see iOS 6.0/6.1/7.0.
[iOS5 Simulator on XCode5-GM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813846/ios5-simulator-on-xcode5-gm)

Answer (score 0):

Additional Simulators can be installed from `Xcode -> Preference -> Downloads -> Components`

[image]

However, in case of Xcode 5.x iOS 5 simulator cannot be installed since Mavericks doesn’t allows it.

[image]

[Apple document for Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1)