# Images.xcassets and IOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5.1, xcasset

My app is almost complete and i'm bug testing and fixing.
Now this is the first time i have used images xcassets and until now it worked.

When i'm testing on the simulator all icons look great, when testing on my test devices iPhone 5, iPad mini, iPhone 4 iOS 6 and iPad 2 iOS 6 everything looks great.

But when i test on the iPad 1 with IOS 5 the icon is blurry, but the ipad 2 uses the same icon set.
So i changed that icon to red (others are bleu) and on IOS 6 the icon turns red.
The iPad 1 does not change the icon so its using a different icon set.

How do i make the iPad 1 on IOS 5 use the iPad App IOS 5,6 72pt icon?

info about the icon:

1. 1x size = 72X72
2. 2X size = 144X144
3. Tried the naming convention.

[image: Icons]

(I removed the icon in the center, because the app is not yet released)

---

___________________________________________UPDATE___________________________________________________

After a while i stopped using the xcassets for my app. It's simply IOS 5 that is giving the problem.
It seems that Apple just want's us to stop with IOS 5, xcode 5 and mavericks just makes it too big of a deal to make iOS 5 apps and test them. I'm expecting to stop iOS 5 development next year.

Comment: Have you tried to completely remove the app from the iPad 1? iOS get easily confused if you deploy multiple times from Xcode. The main problem is that Xcode only adds files to the app bundle, it never removes any files. So it's quite easy to get conflicting files and iOS chooses the wrong one. Remove the app to rule out such a problem first.

Comment: @ Matthias Bauch Yes i have removed the app several times, and to be absolutely sure reseted the iPad.

Comment: Clean&Build the project. Also run the app to iPad Simulator with iOS 5 to see if it shows the correct app icon.

Comment: @NikosM. Tried Clean&Build  and the iOS 5 simulator is not available for OS X mavericks with Xcode 5.

Comment: You can install iOS 5 simulator from an older xcode installation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540739/xcode-5-0-1-and-ios-5-1-simulator-issue

Comment: @NikosM. I moved my app to an older machine with the iOS 5 simulator. But the icon is still blurry. I'm dropping the assets catalog, its taking to long.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the iPad 1 and iOS 5.

But I found an unsightly workaround for this problem. Build your project for an iOS device and not for the simulator. Go to the .app file in the finder and open the package content (right click).
As you can see, there are the AppIcons for the iPad named "filename"~ipad.png and (if available) the AppIcons for the iPhone named "filename".png.
Remove the "~ipad" string from the image filenames and build your project again - should work no.

If your target also supports the iPhone, this solution won't work I think.

The same problem also comes up, if you set up a complete new project with XCode 5 and deployment target iOS 5 on the iPad. I've already reported this to apple.