# Xcode 5.0 testing in iOS 5.0.1 Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios-simulator, xcode5

I have a customer who has reported an issue that my app instantly crashes after starting on iOS 5.0.1 on an iPad 1, and I wanted to test it.

How is it possible to run an app with Xcode 5.0 on an iOS 5.0.1 Simulator, as it is not shown in the list of available downloads.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540739/xcode-5-0-1-and-ios-5-1-simulator-issue), it might help. (Please note that I haven't tried it.)

If it really is impossible on Mavericks, maybe you could consider installing an older OS X version in a VM?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already seen this post and tried the given solution, but there is no other Xcode installation left on my Mac :/ But it seems right, that there is no way of testing on iOS5.0.1 with Mavericks.

Comment: I don't know if this is worth playing with, but maybe a Lion VM could let you install Xcode 4.x and debug your iOS 5 app? Here are [instructions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/how-can-i-install-mac-os-x-lion-in-virtualbox-or-any-other-type-of-virtual-mach) (that I did not tried).